# Get list of dependencies and their versions programmatically in iOS application

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift-package-manager, carthage

I need to get all the libraries and their dependencies **versions** inside an iOS application and send the information to the Server for an automated process we do later on.

For CocoaPods -
Is there a way to write a Pod hook in Ruby that will read the Manifest.lock or Podfile.lock files programmatically to an info.plist after doing 'pod install' and then reads it by using Swift/Obj-c?

Unfortunately, I'm not experienced in Ruby so I just need to know if this approach is something that's even possible to implement or we can't have any access to the Pod files from the Application's code.

Not sure if there is a solution for the above if it fits SPM and Carthage as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can install the [cocoapods-acknowledgements](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-acknowledgements) CocoaPods Plugin, that generates a plist of all the libraries and their license information. This will create a metadata.plist file in the Pods folder. Then you can upload it by executing a curl command in the [post_install](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#post_install) hook, that is executed after a pod install/update.

```
post_install do |installer|
   exec "curl -d @Pods/metadata.plist https://myServer"
end
```